# Inconveniente conexión SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

buen día, instale oracle 11G XE, lo configure e ingrese directamente por SQL PLUS sin inconvenientes, al momento de realizar la conexión con SQL Developer se me presenta un error llamado "No hay mas datos para leer del Socket", a continuación evidencio mi archivo listener.ora y tsnames.ora junto con el respectivo error, agradezco su colaboración.

Agrego información:

```
LISTENER.ORA:

# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Home\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\Home\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\Home\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = Home-PC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )



TSNAMES:

# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\Home\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
LISTENER_ORCL =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = Home-PC) (PORT = 1521))
ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

[image: IMAGEN ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

1. Intenta entrar a los servicios  "service.msc" desde Windows + R y de ahí buscas el servicio de "OracleServiceXE", y lo inicias o reinicias con la opción del botón secundario del mouse.
2. Si te muestra error: No hay más datos para leer del socket
3. Abre archivo `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`
4. Cambia `(SERVER = DEDICATED)` a `(SERVER = SHARED)`
5. Reinicia la BD y el listener.